# The performance of transaction_isolation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, isolation-level

I know that `transaction_isolation` has 4 valid values: `READ-UNCOMMITTED`, `READ-COMMITTED`, `REPEATABLE-READ`, `SERIALIZABLE`, and the order above is from highest amount of consistency and protection to the least [[Official Doc]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level).

Intuitively, [Constraining database access operation execution typically means reduced performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)). Also, as described [here](https://logicalread.com/optimize-mysql-perf-part-2-mc13/#.Xv3r95MzZhF), `READ-UNCOMMITTED` should have the best performance among the four.

**However**, I run a test:

```sh
./mysql-test-run.pl \
--debug-server \
--clean-vardir \
--force-restart \
--report-times \
--max-connections=16 \
--testcase-timeout=60 \
--combination=--transaction-isolation=SERIALIZABLE \
--combination=--transaction-isolation=REPEATABLE-READ \
--combination=--transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED \
--combination=--transaction-isolation=READ-UNCOMMITTED \
--repeat=100 \
main.innodb_deadlock
```

and got the following results (measured by time spent in ms):
[image]
`READ-UNCOMMITTED` results in the worst performance. Does the result right?

Thanks!

Comment: That's way too much chart, and this is also off-topic here. See [the DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research.

Answer (score 2):

> Intuitively, Constraining database access operation execution typically means reduced performance.

Sorry, your intuition is not serving you well in this case.

Isolation levels should have no significant effect on query execution performance, and you should not choose an isolation level to "get better performance." They affect locking behavior for some queries, which only matters if you have concurrent queries that need to acquire locks.

Depending on the isolation level, they might have to *wait* for the locks if another session holds the locks. Queries don't start execution time until they acquire the locks they need.

If you've looked at the MySQL slow query log, you might have noticed that it reports `Query_time` separately from `Lock_time`. In a system that appears to be slow, it could be that way even if average query time is very low, but queries had to wait in a queue to acquire locks.

Once it gets the locks they need, a query executes as fast in one isolation level as in another level.

P.S.: I have never found any good reason to use READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level. That's just a bad idea to allow a session to view partially-completed changes from other sessions. It breaks the assurance of atomic changes.

Comment: "Isolation levels should have no significant effect on query execution performance." I'm not sure this is exact, because of MVCC. For example, in REPEATABLE READ, MySQL has to keep a lot of undo logs to satisfy transaction-wide consistency; for the reader, this means potentially restoring hundreds of versions for each scanned row. It's fairly easy to reproduce this effect and the associated slowdown in a test environment.

Comment: Granted, there are edge cases that contradict any general rule. If you use REPEATABLE READ, *AND* you make multiple read queries during a transaction that is long-lived, *AND* you are also making concurrent updates to the same data at a high rate, you might force your read queries to traverse back-pointers into the undo tablespace. But this is still not a good reason to change the transaction isolation level. Use the isolation level that supports your application requirements.